# add quotes to each string and change the delimiter for a comma

Tags: delimiter-matching, search-replace

I have this string:

```
private | public-read | public-read-write | authenticated-read | aws-exec-read | bucket-owner-read | bucket-owner-full-control
```

I would like to find a mnemonic or easy pattern that could allow me to achieve this:

```
"private" , "public-read", "public-read-write", "authenticated-read", "aws-exec-read", "bucket-owner-read","bucket-owner-full-control"
```

If am trying first with `\w`:

```
s/\(\w\+\)/"\1"/g
```

But problem is that ignore the colon and returns:

```
"public"-"read"-"write"
```

instead of:

```
"public-read-write"
```

Any ideas, tips?

Comment: Possible options: `[^ |]` (anything not a bar or space); `\k` if `-` is in iskeyword; `\f` might work if space isn’t in isfname, though both this and the former may or may not grab the bars (I’m mot sure);

Answer (score 2):

You can break this up into 3 substitutions and apply them in sequence:

```
:s/ | /", "/g | s/^/"/ | s/$/"/
```

- `s/ | /", "/g` replaces all the `|` delimiters with the quote and commas.
- `| s/^/"/` a second substitution places a quote at the start of the line.
- `| s/$/"/` a third substitution places a quote at the end of the line.